# SharePoint 2013 SharePoint-hosted remote event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-2013, event-receiver

I am running a SharePoint-hosted remote event receiver in SharePoint 2013.

I am quite confused about the concept of SharePoint-hosted app, MSDN mentioned that the app logics are all running in user's browser, does it mean when we click on the SharePoint list, the remote event receiver app is actually loaded in my browser?

Answer (score 1):

Remote Event Receivers are not available in SharePoint-hosted, despite being available to create in VS. You'd need to create Provider-hosted app to achieve that.